# Window will only update on mouse move

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi

I have a problem with a test GUI I am programming. I would like to display the amount of time that the GUI has been running, and have this count updated on every second (or so). My problem is, my GUI only updates the time when I move my mouse.

I have stepped through my program, adding a break point right before the InvalidateRect() call. When I have this break point in, I can see the handle hwndTimeOn get updated (basically when my program breaked I would then press F5 and I see that the handle gets updated with the correct count every time). But when I run my program without the break point, my handle is only updated when I move my mouse around...could that mean that my main window is losing focus (or is not active) and therefore doesnt correctly update my hwndTimeOn? I'm not sure what else could be the real cause, I do not have any message handling for mouse moves or clicks in my window process function and I do not update my handle hwndTimeOn anywhere else in my program.

Heres some code:

Some variables used:

```
CString temp, timeDiff;
time_t startCount, now, start;
double diffTime;
```

For the time reading text edit handle:

```
hwndTimeOn= CreateWindowEx(NULL,
    "EDIT",
    "Time On",
    WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE |
    WS_CHILD,
    520,
    5,
    100,
    24,
    hwnd,
    (HMENU)IDC_TIMEON,
    GetModuleHandle(NULL),
    NULL);
```

Inside my message loop:

```
if (difftime(now, startCount) > 1)
    {
        diffTime = difftime(now, start);
        temp.Format("%f", diffTime);
        timeDiff = "Time On: ";
        timeDiff.Append(temp);

        SetWindowText(hwndTimeOn, timeDiff);

        InvalidateRect(hwndTimeOn, NULL, TRUE);
        startCount = now;
    }
```

Comment: No. It means that a time change does not post a Windows message that would cause your message loop to be entered. In order to do what you want, you need to use a Windows timer, which will send a WM_TIMER event to the window; in response to that event, you can update your UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No messages are being posted to the window when it's idle, that's why `GetMessage` doesn't return and the code inside the message loop isn't being run.

When you move your mouse, the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message is being posted, and as a side effect, the program also has the chance to run the code inside the message loop.

As @KenWhite mentioned in the comments, use `WM_TIMER`. It was designed for those kinds of tasks.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didnt realize that no messages are posted to the window when its in idle, that makes a lot of sense now that you mention it

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just a question, which is the frequency of the WM_TIMER event? I mean it is fired every second? half-second?

Comment: @Miguel you decide. See the documentation of [SetTimer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-settimer).